# "Auf dass" und "damit" Sätze in der Vergangenheit

Tags: conjunction, modal-verb, time, past

Ich bin auf folgende Fragestellung gestoßen: Welche Zeitform benutzt man bei einem "auf dass"-Satz, wenn der Hauptsatz im Perfekt oder im Präteritum steht. Hierbei ist es wichtig, dass der Nebensatz ebenso abgeschlossen sein muss. Das folgende Beispiel handelt somit von einem Ereignis, welches bspw. vor 20 Jahren stattgefunden hat. Die Bezugsperson ist nicht mehr am Leben und kann die Erwartung nicht mehr erfüllen.

> Wir haben ihn geschlagen/schlugen ihn, auf dass er anflehen möge.

Oder muss es doch so sein:

> Wir haben ihn geschlagen/schlugen ihn, auf dass er anflehen mochte.

Dasselbe gilt natürlich auch für "damit".

Ich bitte um eine ausführliche Erklärung, da es mir nicht möglich war, im Internet eine Antwort auf diese Frage zu finden. Vielen Dank im Voraus.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Wer soll angefleht werden? Mir scheint da ein "uns" zu fehlen. Also die Folter war zuerst und mit dem Ziel, dass der Geschlagene um Gnade bettelt? Und beides ca. 20 Jahre her? Hm, mir fallen grad verschiedene Varianten ein, weil ich es mit den Regeln nicht so genau nehme.

Comment: ", auf dass er ... möge" ist korrekt, aber ziemlich altertümlich und würde heute normalerweise allenfalls im ironischen Sinn verwendet werden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob hier das richtige Verb verwendet wurde

- **anflehen** = ängstlich oder verzweifelt um etwas bitten
  Dieses Wort ist ein transitives Verb. Wenn man es verwendet, muss man in einem Akkusativobjekt angeben, an wen man die Bitte richtet:

  > Klaus flehte **seinen Peiniger** an, doch endlich aufzuhören.
  > Der Bettler flehte **die Passanten** um ein Stück Brot an.
- **fliehen** = schnelles Verlassen eines gefährlichen Ortes
  Dieses Wort benötigt kein Akkusativobjekt.

  > Klaus floh vor seinem Peiniger.
  > Die Einwohner flohen aus dem Kampfgebiet.

Daher ist der Teil *»auf dass er anflehen möge«* sowieso falsch. Richtig ist einer dieser beiden Sätze:

> *Ängstlich bitten:* Wir schlugen ihn, auf dass er **uns** anflehen möge.
> *Davonlaufen:* Wir schlugen ihn, auf dass er **fliehen** möge.

Ich kenne den Kontext nicht. Ohne Kontext ergibt der zweite Satz für mich mehr Sinn, daher nehme ich ihn als Beispiel. Alles kann aber auch deckungsgleich auf den ersten Satz angewendet werden.

---

### Subjunktion

Die Wortfolge *»auf dass«* ist eine begründende Subjunktion. Das bedeutet, dass sie einen untergeordneten Nebensatz einleitet, den man *»Konjunktionalsatz«* nennt, und dieser Konjunktionalsatz enthält eine Begründung für das was im Hauptsatz gesagt wird. Ein Konjunktionalsatz ist immer ein Teil eines größeren Satzes, der von einer Subjunktion eingeleitet wird und bei dem das finite Verb (jenes Verb, das gebeugt wird) ganz am Ende steht.

**Begründungssätze**

> Er legte sich ins Bett, **weil er müde war.**
> **Da es so heiß war** fuhren sie an den See.
> Lisa ging heim, **damit sie endlich Ruhe hatte.**
> Lisa ging heim, **auf dass sie endlich Ruhe habe.**

---

### Synonym von »damit«

Die Wortfolge *»auf dass«* kann immer durch das Wort *»damit«* ersetzt werden. Beides bedeutet genau dasselbe und auch grammatisch funktionieren beide Ausdrücke fast genau gleich. *»Auf dass«* (in alter Rechtschreibung: *»auf daß«*) ist aber eine veraltete Form, die rund um das Jahr 1850 den Höhepunkt ihrer Beliebtheit hatte, aber auch damals wurde *»damit«* etwa 40-mal häufiger verwendet als *»auf daß«.* Heute kommt in deutschen Texten auf eine Verwendung von *»auf dass«* rund 300-mal *»damit«.* Wer gutes modernes Deutsch sprechen und schreiben will, sollte auf *»auf dass«* daher eher verzichten und stattdessen *»damit«* sagen und schreiben.

Das eben Gesagte gilt jedoch nur für die Subjunktion. Das Wort *»damit«* kann nämlich auch noch als Pronominaladverb verwendet werden, in dieser Funktion kann es nicht durch *»auf dass«* ersetzt werden:

- **Subjunktion**

  > Der Hamster legt Vorräte an, **damit** er im Winter Futter hat.
  > **Damit** die Verbindung lange hält muss man den Kleber gut trocknen lassen.
- **Pronominaladverb:**

  > Er nahm den Hammer und schlug **damit** den Nagel in die Wand.
  > »Her **damit**!« rief der Räuber als er das Geld sah.
  > Der Ritter heiratete die Prinzessin und **damit** endete das Märchen.

---

### Modus

Ich habe oben geschrieben, dass *»auf dass«* grammatisch **fast** gleich wie *»damit«* funktioniert. Die Gleichheit bezieht sich auf den Satzbau, aber es gibt einen wichtigen Unterschied beim Modus des finiten Verbs:

- **Indikativ**

  > Lasset uns trinken, **damit** wir fröhlich **sind.**
  > Der Hamster legt Vorräte an, **damit** er im Winter Futter **hat.**
- **Konjunktiv I**

  > Lasset uns trinken, **auf dass** wir fröhlich **seien.**
  > Der Hamster legt Vorräte an, **auf dass** er im Winter Futter **habe.**

Das ist eine Eigenheit von *»auf dass«,* die es bei anderen Subjunktionen nicht gibt.

---

### Das Verb »mögen« als Modalverb

Das ist vermutlich die schwierigste Sache an dem Beispielsatz. Dieses Verb verändert nämlich seine Bedeutung wenn man es im Konjunktiv verwendet.

- Modalverben mit Infinitv im Indikativ

  > Erich **kann** schwimmen.
  > Lisa **soll** schlafen.
  > Heinrich **muss** essen.
  >
  > Anna **möchte** fortgehen.
- dieselben Modalverben im Konjunktiv I

  > Heinz sagt, Erich **könne** schwimmen.
  > Heinz sagt, Lisa **solle** schlafen.
  > Heinz sagt, Heinrich **müsse** essen.
  >
  > <del>Heinz sagt, Anna **möge** fortgehen.</del>
  > Heinz verlangt von Anna, sie **möge** fortgehen.

Man kann das Modalverb *mögen* nicht im Konjunktiv verwenden um eine indirekte Rede abzubilden. Stattdessen drückt der Konjunktiv *»möge«* eine von jemand anderm kommende Aufforderung aus, während der Indikativ noch einen eigenen Wunsch ausdrückt.

Die Modalverben *sollen* und *müssen* drücken im Konjunktiv zwar auch eine von außen kommende Aufforderung aus, das tun sie aber auch schon im Indikativ. Hier verändert sich die Bedeutung also nicht. Bei *»mögen«* kommt es aber zu dieser Veränderung der Bedeutung.

Die Form *»mochte«* ist kein Konjunktiv, sondern die ganz normale Vergangenheitsform von *mögen* im Indikativ:

> Präsens Indikativ: Heute möchte Klaus schlafen.
> Präteritum Indikativ: Gestern mochte Klaus schlafen.

Der Satz aus der Frage enthält im untergeordneten Teilsatz die Begründung für das Schlagen, diese Begründung ist aber eine Aufforderung:

> Er soll fliehen. Aus diesem Grund schlagen wir ihn.

Diese Aufforderung funktioniert aber nicht wenn das Modalverb *»mögen«* im Indikativ steht:

- Indikativ, Präteritum

  > Er mochte fliehen. Aus diesem Grund schlugen wir ihn.
- Konjunktiv I, Präsens

  > Er möge fliehen. Aus diesem Grund schlagen wir ihn.

Schwierig wird es, wenn man die Aufforderung in die Vergangenheit setzen will. Eigentlich wäre der Konjunktiv II die korrekte Wahl:

- Konjunktiv II, Präteritum

  > Er möchte fliehen. Aus diesem Grund schlugen wir ihn.
  > Wir schlugen ihn, auf dass er fliehen möchte.

Das ist aber eine so ungewöhnliche Konstruktion, dass die im 21. Jahrhundert kaum noch verstanden wird. Ich persönlich würde daher an dieser Stelle den Konjunktiv II durch den Konjunktiv I ersetzen:

- Konjunktiv I, Präteritum

  > Er möge fliehen. Aus diesem Grund schlugen wir ihn.
  > Wir schlugen ihn, auf dass er fliehen möge.

---

### Umschreibung

Bei so komplizierten Konstruktionen ist es oft hilfreich, den Satz völlig anders zu formulieren:

> Wir schlugen ihn, um ihn dazu zu bringen, die Flucht zu ergreifen.

Und falls es doch um eine Bitte ging:

> Wir schlugen ihn, um ihn dazu zu bringen, uns anzuflehen.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort. Das Beispiel ist beliebig austauschbar und das mit dem "uns" anflehen war ein unbeabsichtigter Fehler. Wenn ich Sie richtig verstanden habe, muss es dann mit auf dass immer möge sein, auf keinen Fall mochte. Anderes Beispiel: Sie haben die römischen Soldaten belohnt, auf dass sie gut kämpfen mögen. Nicht mochten! Und ja mir ist bewusst, dass "damit" die bessere Variante ist, jedoch handelte es sich hier um eine altertümliche Aussage. Bei damit würde denke ich dasselbe gelten. Ich bedanke mich nochmals für die ausführliche Erklärung.

Comment: Wieso klärst Du nicht erst, was gemeint ist, mit Hilfe von Kommentaren?

Answer (score 3):

Zuerst: der Nebensatz geht so nicht wirklich.  *Anflehen* braucht ein Objekt.  Ich werde, da ich den Kontext nicht kenne, hier stattdessen *gestehen* verwenden.

*Auf dass* ist eine recht altertümliche Konstruktion, wie in den Kommentaren bemerkt wurde, daher sind wohl auch die Regeln dafür in heutiger Sprache nicht ganz so fest etabliert.  Es handelt sich, würde ich sagen, um eine zwei Aspekte umfassende Bildung: die Beschreibung eines zukünftigen Zustandes, mit dem Wunsch, dass dieser eintreten möge.

Zur Consecutio Temporum ist zunächst zu sagen, dass die Zeitlichkeit des untergeordneten Satzes immer relativ zum Hauptsatz besteht:

> *Wir haben gesehen, dass er gegangen ist* (bevor wir es gesehen haben)

> *Wir haben gesehen, dass er geht* (während wir es gesehen haben)

> *Wir haben gesehen, dass er gehen wird* (Schluss auf den Zustand, nachdem wir ihn gesehen haben)

Letzteres kann man, Zukunft auch immer unsicher ist und es außerdem nicht alle Zeitrelationen im Futur gibt, auch ausdrücken als

> *Wir haben gesehn, dass er gehen würde*

Letzteres ist nun, meiner Meinung nach, die einzige Art, auf die *auf dass* funktioniert:

> *Wir haben ihn geschlagen, auf dass er gestehen möge.*

Die Hauptzeit ist die des Schlagens, relativ zu welcher wir über die Zukunft sprechen.  Wie gesagt, zusammen mit dem Wunsch-Aspekt: wir müssen auch wollen, dass er gesteht!  Folgendes geht nicht:

> **Wir haben ihn gesehen, auf dass er gehen möge* (kein Wunsch!)

> **Wir haben ihn geschlagen, auf dass er gestanden hat* (keine Zukunft!)

Ebenfalls zulässig ist, würde ich sagen,

> *Wir haben ihn geschlagen, auf dass er gesteht*

weil dabei das Präsens das Futur ausdrückt, wie so oft; allerdings geht ohne den Konjunktiv ein guter Teil des altertümlichen Stils verloren, sowie der Wunschaspekt.

Comment: Ebenfalls vielen Dank für die Erklärung. Wie auch in dem anderen Kommentar erwähnt, war das mit dem uns anflehen ein Fehler meinerseits. Ansonsten ist das Beispiel beliebig austauschbar. Ich habe nun verstanden, dass es mit auf dass immer möge sein muss und nicht mochte.

Comment: Wieso klärst Du nicht erst, was gemeint ist, mit Hilfe von Kommentaren?

Comment: @userunknown Weil es für die Grammatik im Nebensatz irrelevant ist.